# bootstrap classes to show form validation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The below is the html code and it denotes it is a mandatory field.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': data.projName.$error.required }">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projName"
                                   ng-model="myModel.projName" required>

    </div>
```

As mentioned above `ng-class="{'has-error':data.projName.$error.required }"` , i want to mentioned for the below input field which should only accept numbers, if user enters anything else other than numbers it should show the error message and user should not able to submit the form.

```
 <div class="form-group">
       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="digitalId" ng-model="myModel.digitalId" placeholder="Enter only numbers">
                    </div>
```

How can i achieve the above scenario using simple bootstrap classes which shows error message when user enters some characters in the input field which should only accept numbers.

Comment: use http://formvalidation.io/. It is easy to use.

Comment: I cannot use any other API. I know bootstrap from validation supports it, but unable to find the examples...